# Передать значение datetimepicker элементу

Tags: jquery

есть форма, где нужно выбрать период даты с помощью плагина datetimepicker,

```
$(function () {
    $("#datetimepicker7").datetimepicker({
        minDate: moment(),
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        locale: '<?=$_SESSION["lang"]?>'
  });
    $("#datetimepicker8").datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        locale: '<?=$_SESSION["lang"]?>'
    });
    $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker8').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker8").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

вопрос в том, как передать выбранное время атрибуту value данного поля для того, чтобы в последствии можно было записать в базу данных

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
     format:'d.m.Y H:i',
     lang:'ru',
   });
   

   $("#getDateTime").on('click', function(){
     let dt =  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker('getValue');
     console.log(dt);
     console.log(dt.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + dt.toLocaleTimeString());
   });
   
 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='datetimepicker1' />
<a href='#' id='getDateTime'>getValue</a>
```

Comment: плагин не datepicker  а datetimepicker, а в консоле пишет  TypeError: option onSelect is not recognized!